# Unexpected behavior for python set.__contains__

Tags: python, list, set

Borrowing the documentation from the `__contains__` documentation

```
print set.__contains__.__doc__
x.__contains__(y) <==> y in x.
```

This seems to work fine for primitive objects such as int, basestring, etc. But for user-defined objects that define the `__ne__` and `__eq__` methods, I get unexpected behavior. Here is a sample code:

```
class CA(object):
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name

  def __eq__(self,other):
    if self.name == other.name:
      return True
    return False

  def __ne__(self,other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)

obj1 = CA('hello')
obj2 = CA('hello')

theList = [obj1,]
theSet = set(theList)

# Test 1: list
print (obj2 in theList)  # return True

# Test 2: set weird
print (obj2 in theSet)  # return False  unexpected

# Test 3: iterating over the set
found = False
for x in theSet:
  if x == obj2:
    found = True

print found   # return True

# Test 4: Typcasting the set to a list
print (obj2 in list(theSet))  # return True
```

So is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: this question should be on display here at stackoverflow: **how to ask questions**. clear to the point, with a small example illustrating the problem. as others have answered here, sets use hash values or else they would get the preformance of lists..

Comment: style note: use `return self.name == other.name` instead of `if cond: return True \n return False`

Answer (score 7):

For `set`s and `dicts`, you need to define [`__hash__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.hash). Any two objects that are equal should hash the same in order to get consistent / expected behavior in `set`s and `dicts`.

I would reccomend using a `_key` method, and then just referencing that anywhere you need the part of the item to compare, just as you call `__eq__` from `__ne__` instead of reimplementing it:

```
class CA(object):
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name

  def _key(self):
    return type(self), self.name

  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self._key())

  def __eq__(self,other):
    if self._key() == other._key():
      return True
    return False

  def __ne__(self,other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because `CA` doesn't implement [`__hash__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

A sensible implementation would be:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.name)
```

Answer (score 2):

A `set` *hashes* it's elements to allow a fast lookup. You have to overwrite the `__hash__` method so that a element can be found:

```
class CA(object):
  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.name)
```

Lists don't use hashing, but compare each element like your `for` loop does.