# Python 2: different meaning of the 'in' keyword for sets and lists

Tags: python, list, set, equality

Consider this snippet:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, someattribute="somevalue"):
        self.someattribute = someattribute

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.someattribute == other.someattribute

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

list_of_objects = [SomeClass()]
print(SomeClass() in list_of_objects)

set_of_objects = set([SomeClass()])
print(SomeClass() in set_of_objects)
```

which evaluates to:

```
True
False
```

Can anyone explain why the 'in' keyword has a different meaning for sets and lists?
I would have expected both to return True, especially when the type being tested has equality methods defined.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549709/unexpected-behavior-for-python-set-contains .. incidentally, in Python 3 running this code hints at what's going on: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'SomeClass'"

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's all clear now.

Comment: BTW, you do know that your `someattribute` here is a **class** attribute and not an **instance** attribute, right? You *have* heard of `__init__`, right?

Comment: @Karl: yep, edited for realism

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The meaning is the same, but the implementation is different.  Lists simply examine each object, checking for equality, so it works for your class.  Sets first hash the objects, and if they don't implement hash properly, the set appears not to work.

Your class defines `__eq__`, but doesn't define `__hash__`, and so won't work properly for sets or as keys of dictionaries.  The rule for `__eq__` and `__hash__` is that two objects that `__eq__` as True must also have equal hashes.  By default, objects hash based on their memory address.  So your two objects that are equal by your definition don't provide the same hash, so they break the rule about `__eq__` and `__hash__`.

If you provide a `__hash__` implementation, it will work fine. For your sample code, it could be:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.someattribute)
```

Comment: This is one of the things that Python 3 handles more clearly: it will refuse to make a set out of any object that doesn't have a `__hash__()`. Python 2 has a default `__hash__()` that reflects object identity rather than equality.

Comment: Actually, what happened is that classic classes behaved the same way (not defining a `__hash__` method would give you a default that raised a TypeError if you did define `__cmp__` and/or `__eq__`,) but then new-style classes were introduced (in Python 2.2) and that behaviour wasn't correctly copied over. That oversight was missed for enough releases that changing it would potentially break too much code, so fixing it was delayed until Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

In pretty much any hashtable implementation, including Python's, if you override the equality method you must override the hashing method (in Python, this is [`__hash__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)).  The `in` operator for lists just checks equality with every element of the list, which the `in` operator for sets first hashes the object you are looking for, checks for an object in that slot of the hashtable, and then checks for equality if there is anything in the slot.  So, if you override `__eq__` without overriding `__hash__`, you cannot be guaranteed that the `in` operator for sets will check in the right slot.

Answer (score 1):

Define `__hash__()` method that corresponds to your `__eq__()` method. [Example](http://ideone.com/CFtOy).