# Object membership in sets

Tags: python, class, operators, membership

This is really two questions:

1. Why isn't the membership operator (__contains__) ever being called?
2. Why is D in nodeList, but not in nodeSet?

My goal is for D to be "in" both nodeList and nodeSet, because it has the same loc as A.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, loc):
        self.loc = loc

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print "eq: self.getLoc(): {}, other.getLoc(): {}".format(self.getLoc(),     other.getLoc())
        if self.getLoc() == other.getLoc():
            return True
        return False

    def __contains__(self, other):
        print "contains: self.getLoc(): {}, other.getLoc(): {}".format(self.getLoc(),  other.getLoc())
        if self.getLoc() == other.getLoc():

            return True
        return False

    def setLoc(self, loc):
        self.loc = loc

    def getLoc(self):
        return self.loc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = Node((1,1))
    B = Node((2,2))
    C = Node((3,3))

    D = Node((1,1))

    nodeList = [A, B, C]
    nodeSet = set()
    nodeSet.add(A)
    nodeSet.add(B)
    nodeSet.add(C)

    print "A in nodeList: {}".format(A in nodeList)
    print "A in nodeSet: {}".format(A in nodeSet)
    print "D in nodeList: {}".format(D in nodeList)
    print "D in nodeSet: {}".format(D in nodeSet)
```

This returns True, True, True, False. Apparently, the __contains__ operator is never called. I would like it to return True, True, True, True.

Any other critiques of my code are of course welcome, as I am a python beginner.

Comment: 1. `__contains__` is called when you ask an object whether there is another object in it.  Here, the `__contains__` method of `nodeList` and `nodeSet` are being called, not `Node`'s.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7549733/487339) -- in short, you need to define `__hash__` if you want to get `D in nodeSet` to return True.  As an aside, we generally don't use getters and setters unless they're necessary (which is relatively rare.)

Comment: @DSM and then you use properties not getters and setters.

Comment: @DSM - Thanks so much for your answer and the link, it helped me immensely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [the documentation re `__hash__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) - in short:

> [I]f [a class] defines `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`,
>   its instances will not be usable in hashed collections.

A `set` is a hashed collection. You'll want to make sure you implement `Node.__hash__()`

Comment: While what you write is true, the poster's actual problem is that __contains__ is implemented on the wrong class.

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that, thanks, but this should at least answer their second question

Answer (score 3):

Why would `Node.__contains__` ever be called? You never have a `Node` as the right-hand-side of an `in` expression.